# Animations in angular js check if an element is being tweened greenscok

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, gsap

I was just wondering is there a better way to do this? I am trying to find a way that I can check if the animation is running on the element if it is dis-regard the click command that is causing the animation so there is no duplicate element showing or repeating animations.  Here is the code it's working I used a factory to store the animating variable and if the variable is true it won't start a new animation.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Animate">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Js animation</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/greensock/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jsanim.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam natus ipsa libero nisi labore ad pariatur consequatur quasi sint modi porro saepe, cupiditate sed asperiores ullam laudantium sit dolorem. Animi.
                <div class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="app.toggleIt()">click to toggle</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, dolore. Nam reiciendis consequuntur vero assumenda facere illum non modi vitae in et perferendis labore pariatur, sed, obcaecati nisi dignissimos quae?</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, dolore. Nam reiciendis consequuntur vero assumenda facere illum non modi vitae in et perferendis labore pariatur, sed, obcaecati nisi dignissimos quae?</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="toggle" ng-if="app.toggle">
                toggle this
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my jsanim file.

```
var app = angular.module("Animate", ['ngAnimate']);

app.factory("Settings", function(){

    var settings = {};
    settings.animating = false;
    return settings;

})

app.controller("AppCtrl", ["$animate", "$scope", "$http", "Settings", function AppCtrl($animate, $scope, $http, Settings){

    var appCtrl = this;

    appCtrl.toggle = true;

    appCtrl.toggleIt = function(){

        // console.log(Settings.animating, "Settings.animating");

        if(!Settings.animating){

            appCtrl.toggle = !appCtrl.toggle;
            console.log(appCtrl.toggle);

        }

    }

}])

app.animation(".toggle", function(Settings){

    return {

        leave:function(element, done){

            Settings.animating = true;
            TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity:0, onComplete:done});

            return function(onDone){

                Settings.animating = false;

            }

        },
        enter:function(element, done){

            Settings.animating = true;
            TweenMax.from(element, 1, {opacity:0, onComplete:done});

            return function(onDone){

                Settings.animating = false;

            }
        }

    }

})
```

Comment: Could possibly ditch the service and do the check for TweenMax.isTweening( element ); in your .toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do that via `TweenMax`.

- `isActive()` (as stated earlier by **@Jonathan Marzullo**)
  [[Documentation]](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/isActive/).
- `TweenMax.getTweensOf()` and `TweenMax.getAllTweens()`
  [[Documentation]](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/getTweensOf/).
- `TweenMax.isTweening()`
  [[Documention]](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/isTweening/).

So in theory, it could be as simple as below without having to rely on external boolean variable:

```
if (!TweenMax.isTweening(element)) TweenMax.to(element, duration,{prop:value});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

GSAP has a method called `isActive()`

http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/isActive/

You can use it by checking the condition of isActive()

```
 if(!tween.isActive()){
        //only do something if the tween is not active
 }
```

Example of its use by GreenSock:

http://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/Pwzomo

Basically `isActive()` indicates whether or not the animation is currently active (meaning the virtual playhead is actively moving across this instance's time span and it is not paused, nor are any of its ancestor timelines).